How to get Evan Chen's neovim settings on Mac
I've been using the TeXShop editor and I want to move to neovim/VimTex. Also I thought that I'd use Evan Chen's GitHub https://github.com/vEnhance/dotfiles?tab=readme-ov-file, because he has some neovim settings there. But I have no idea where to even start. Only thing I've done so far is installing neovim. Please, can you provide some help? Thanks in advance.

If you want to have a nice and easy star with Neovim, I'd rather use something like https://www.lazyvim.org or https://astronvim.com instead of personal dot files. Astronvim has vimtex in the community repo: https://github.com/AstroNvim/astrocommunity/tree/main/lua/astrocommunity/markdown-and-latex

Thanks, I'll check them out.
